# Reference a list of dicts

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary

Python 2.7 on Mint  Cinnamon 17.3.
I have a bit of test code employing a list of dicts and despite many hours of frustration, I cannot seem to work out why it is not working as it should do.

```
blockagedict = {'location': None, 'timestamp': None, 'blocked': None}
blockedlist = [blockagedict]

blockagedict['location'] = 'A'
blockagedict['timestamp'] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:08.702149'
blockagedict['blocked'] = True

blockagedict['location'] = 'B'
blockagedict['timestamp'] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459'
blockagedict['blocked'] = False
blockedlist.append(blockagedict)

for test in blockedlist:
    print test['location'], test['timestamp'], test['blocked']
```

This always produces the following output and I cannot work out why and cannot see if I have anything wrong with my code. It always prints out  the last set of dict values but should print all, if I am not mistaken.

```
B 12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459 False
B 12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459 False
```

I would be happy for someone to show me the error of my ways and put me out of my misery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about performance and will have 1 million dictionaries in a list, all with the same keys, you will be better off using a NumPy structured array.  Then you can have a single, efficient data structure which is basically a matrix of rows and named columns of appropriate types.  You mentioned in a comment that  you may know the number of rows in advance.  Here's a rewrite of your example code using NumPy instead, which will be massively more efficient than a list of a million dicts.

```
import numpy as np

dtype = [('location', str, 1), ('timestamp', str, 27), ('blocked', bool)]

count = 2 # will be much larger in the real program

blockages = np.empty(count, dtype) # use zeros() instead if some data may never be populated

blockages[0]['location'] = 'A'
blockages[0]['timestamp'] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:08.702149'
blockages[0]['blocked'] = True

blockages['location'][1] = 'B' # n.b. indexing works this way too
blockages['timestamp'][1] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459'
blockages['blocked'][1] = False

for test in blockages:
    print test['location'], test['timestamp'], test['blocked']
```

Note that the usage is almost identical.  But the storage is in a fixed size, single allocation.  This will reduce memory usage and compute time.

As a nice side effect, writing it as above completely sidesteps the issue you originally had, with multiple references to the same row.  Now all the data is placed directly into the matrix with no object references at all.

---

Later in a comment you mention you cannot use NumPy because it may not be installed.  Well, we can still avoid unnecessary dicts, like this:

```
from array import array

blockages = {'location': [], 'timestamp': [], 'blocked': array('B')}

blockages['location'].append('A')
blockages['timestamp'].append('12-Apr-2016 01:01:08.702149')
blockages['blocked'].append(True)

blockages['location'].append('B')
blockages['timestamp'].append('12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459')
blockages['blocked'].append(False)

for location, timestamp, blocked in zip(*blockages.values()):
    print location, timestamp, blocked
```

Note I use `array` here for efficient storage of the fixed-size `blocked` values (this way each value takes exactly one byte).

You still end up with resizable lists that you could avoid, but at least  you don't need to store a dict in every slot of the list.  This should still be more efficient.

Comment: I hadn't actually thought of using numpy although I have never used it before, never had a need to.... until now :-)

Comment: Actually, having thought about it, I can't use numpy as I have no control of what gets installed on the machine.

Comment: @DaveJ1961: I've added a moderately efficient non-NumPy solution as well.

Comment: Interesting. I have never used arrays in python before. I don't understand your use of zip here. This is a little above my skill level.

Comment: @DavidJohns: I use `zip` to combine the three sequences into one when iterating.  It's pretty vanilla use of the very handy `zip` function with one quirk: the `*` before `values`.  That `*` is there because `zip` takes N arguments, not a list of N things, so we need to "expand" the arguments with `*`.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the line `blockedlist = [blockagedict]` actually stores a reference to the dict, not a copy, in the list. Your code effectively creates a list that has two references to the very same object.

Comment: And how to fix it?

Comment: You have to think of who owns an object. The clean way IMO would be to create a new dict object for every list element (and pass it to the list completely), not reassign an existing one.

Comment: If I knew the size of the list, could I not initialise the whole list instead of using append? The list will have in the order of 1 to 2 million items.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have initialised the list of dicts right off the bat and this seems to work. Although I am tempted to write a class for this.

```
blockedlist = [{'location': None, 'timestamp': None, 'blocked': None} for k in range(2)]

blockedlist[0]['location'] = 'A'
blockedlist[0]['timestamp'] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:08.702149'
blockedlist[0]['blocked'] = True

blockedlist[1]['location'] = 'B'
blockedlist[1]['timestamp'] = '12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459'
blockedlist[1]['blocked'] = False

for test in blockedlist:
    print test['location'], test['timestamp'], test['blocked']
```

And this produces what I was looking for:

```
A 12-Apr-2016 01:01:08.702149 True
B 12-Apr-2016 01:01:09.312459 False
```

I will be reading from a text file with 1 to 2 million lines, so converting the code to iterate through the lines won't be a problem.